# Loop through the JSON object keys in excel vba

Tags: json, excel, vba, parsing

I am trying to learn about JSON in excel vba so bear me ..
This is JSON sample ..

```js
{"Title":"Close-Up","Year":"1990","Rated":"NOT RATED","Released":"30 Oct 1991","Runtime":"98 min","Genre":"Documentary, Biography, Crime","Director":"Abbas Kiarostami","Writer":"Abbas Kiarostami","Actors":"Hossain Sabzian, Mohsen Makhmalbaf, Abolfazl Ahankhah, Mehrdad Ahankhah","Plot":"The true story of Hossain Sabzian that impersonated the director Mohsen Makhmalbaf to convince a family they would star in his so-called new film.","Language":"Persian, Azerbaijani","Country":"Iran","Awards":"2 wins.","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMzE4Mjc0MjI1N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjI3MzEzMw@@._V1_SX300.jpg","Ratings":[{"Source":"Internet Movie Database","Value":"8.3/10"},{"Source":"Rotten Tomatoes","Value":"88%"}],"Metascore":"N/A","imdbRating":"8.3","imdbVotes":"11,546","imdbID":"tt0100234","Type":"movie","DVD":"19 Feb 2002","BoxOffice":"N/A","Production":"Zeitgeist Films","Website":"http://www.zeitgeistfilm.com/current/closeup/closeup.html","Response":"True"}
```

This is in range("A1")
and I used this code to loop through each key and debug the key and its related value

```
Sub Test()
Dim ws          As Worksheet
Dim jsonObject  As Object
Dim item        As Variant
Dim jsonText    As String

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
jsonText = ws.Cells(1, 1).Value
Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonText)

For Each item In jsonObject.Keys
    Debug.Print item & vbTab & jsonObject(item)
Next item
End Sub
```

The code works well in regular combinations of key and value but encountered an error at the key 'Ratings' as it is not as the others 
How can I print the value of this key without nested loops. I mean to print this output

```
[{"Source":"Internet Movie Database","Value":"8.3/10"},{"Source":"Rotten Tomatoes","Value":"88%"}]
```

Thanks advanced for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you might want to stringify the values :

```
For Each item In jsonObject.Keys
    Debug.Print item, Replace(JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(jsonObject(item)), """", "")
Next item
```

Comment: That's perfect solution. Just one note when dumping the results to the sheet, how can I get rid of the double quotes?

Comment: Nice. Will remember this! +

Comment: Thanks a lot. I could solve it using these lines
`    For Each item In jsonObject.Keys
        ws.Cells(i, 1) = item
        sTemp = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(jsonObject(item))
        ws.Cells(i, 2) = Mid(sTemp, 2, Len(sTemp) - 2)
        i = i + 1
    Next item
`

Comment: Sorry for disturbing it seems that my code is not very accurate. How can I remove double quotes from the start and end of the result?

Comment: @YasserKhalil maybe if you can show me example of what you get and what you want. I didn't test, but you can try the update

Comment: The result "Close-Up" for example are surrounded by quotes. How can I remove those quotes?

Comment: @YasserKhalil as a side note, JSON can also be loaded in Excell with Power Query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42060625/json-to-excel-using-power-query

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use a recursive sub to empty all the dictionaries including those inside the collection. It does have a level of nesting but it is minimal.

```
Public Sub GetInfoFromSheet()
    Dim jsonStr As String, json As Object
    jsonStr = [A1]
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonStr)
    emptyDict json
End Sub

Public Sub emptyDict(ByVal json As Object)
    Dim key As Variant, item As Object
    For Each key In json
        Select Case TypeName(json(key))
        Case "String"
            Debug.Print key & vbTab & json(key)
        Case "Collection"
            For Each item In json(key)
                emptyDict item
            Next
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

---

**Examining your JSON structure:**

You have an initial dictionary, denoted by `{}`, then within this a series of key and values pairs and a collection, denoted by `[]`. That collection is made up also of dictionaries. So, I use a test with `TypeName` to determine if the top level dictionary value is `String` or `Collection`. If it is a `Collection` I recursively call the `emptyDict` sub to write out the results of the inner dictionaries.

[image]

---

To generate the string shown you only need what is in the collection:

```
Option Explicit
'[{"Source":"Internet Movie Database","Value":"8.3/10"},{"Source":"Rotten Tomatoes","Value":"88%"}]
Public Sub GetInfoFromSheet()
    Dim jsonStr As String, json As Object, item As Object, output As String, key As Variant
    jsonStr = [A1]
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonStr)("Ratings")
    For Each item In json
        For Each key In item.keys
            If key = "Value" Then
                output = output & "," & Chr$(34) & key & Chr$(34) & ":" & Chr$(34) & item(key) & Chr$(34) & "}"
            Else
                output = output & ",{" & Chr$(34) & key & Chr$(34) & ":" & Chr$(34) & item(key) & Chr$(34)
            End If
        Next key
    Next
    output = "[" & Replace$(output, ",", vbNullString, , 1) & "]"
    Debug.Print output    
End Sub
```

Comment: That's great and awesome. Thank you very much
Can the values in the nested collections be concatenated as one string for that key 'Ratings' so as to be like I have attached in main post

Comment: Did you need everything? I have update to show how to generate that string.

Comment: That's great. Thanks a lot for awesome help

Comment: Pleasure. Glad to have helped.