# Loop JSON in array for same value in VBA

Tags: json, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to get "image_id" from the below json in different columns of a row.

```
[
{
"spin": "HM4C6L",
"attributes": {
"product name": "Everest Kutilal Coarse Ground Red Chilli Powder ",
},
"bar_code": {
"valid": true,
"id": "89017817",
"type": "UPC"
},
"spin_state": "LIVE",
"meta": {
"updated-by": "undefined"
},
"version": null,
"images": [
{
"image_id": "dvuewrnauxdroqcapjiu",
"image_name": "masala and spice_HM4A7I2C6L_MN.JPG",
"shot_type": "MN"
},
{
"image_id": "tcku7lwarkv8ch0ao9cu",
"image_name": "masala and spice_HM4A7I2C6L_AL1.JPG",
"shot_type": "AL1"
},
{
"image_id": "b2znlmm59plprrkmkujs",
"image_name": "masala and spice_HM4A7I2C6L_AL2.jpg",
"shot_type": "AL2"
}
]
}
]
```

I tried [Cannot iterate when parsing HTML table using JSON-VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48703168/cannot-iterate-when-parsing-html-table-using-json-vba/48715323#48715323) and [Loop through the JSON object keys in excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52802692/loop-through-the-json-object-keys-in-excel-vba).

```vb
Sub getimage()

Dim current As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim a, b, strUrl As String
Dim count As Variant

Set current = ActiveWorkbook

For Each sht In current.Worksheets

    On Error Resume Next
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set HTTPReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    count = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.count

    For i = 2 To count

        a = CStr(Range("A" & i).Value)
        HTTPReq.Open "GET", "link" & a, False
        HTTPReq.send
        'Debug.Print HTTPReq.ResponseText

        Dim Json, item As Object
        Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(HTTPReq.ResponseText)

        For Each item In Json
            Debug.Print item("images")
            sht.Cells(i, B) = item("image_id")("1")
            sht.Cells(i, B) = item("image_id")("2")    
        next Item

    Next i
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End If
Next sht

End Sub
```

I need "dvuewrnauxdroqcapjiu" in cell B2, tcku7lwarkv8ch0ao9cu in cell C2, and "b2znlmm59plprrkmkujs" in cell C2, but my code is giving no output, no error.

Comment: Probably somewhere an error happens. Remove the `On Error Resume Next`, let the code run again and check if any error is throws, in which line it occurs and what it says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A number of things.

1. Your json is malformed. There is an extra "," here:

```
"Everest Kutilal Coarse Ground Red Chilli Powder ",
```

which means jsonconverter will throw an error. The "," at the end would be to separate the current key-value pair from the next. There isn't a following pair so it should be removed.

2. Your path for accessing is wrong.

Here I am reading the corrected json from cell A1

```
Option Explicit   
Public Sub test()
    Dim json As Object, i As Long, item As Object, c As Long
    i = 2: c = 2
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson([A1])(1)("images")
    For Each item In json
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, c) = item("image_id")
        c = c + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

3. `Cells(2,B)` will expect B to be a variable as string literals are wrapped in "" i.e. "B". Also, you need a counter variable which is incremented or you will keep writing to the same cell.

Comment: Great. Is there a link of how to read the JSON files and detect if the JSON is correct or not?

Comment: Most json viewers will do this for you in terms of validation but you can also use specific validators e.g. https://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidator

Comment: thanks for the answer and link to validate json. I checked my json over https://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidator, its shows "Valid JSON". however, the code you provided did help me.. the correct code : Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(A1)(1)(["images"])  Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hi, then your json is not the same as you posted in the question. If you paste the json above it will error. But glad we got there :-)

Comment: Yes, I just checked.. Sorry... I could not share the original so i made some changes manually, i would have done some mistake then.. But anyways, u did solve my problem.. Thanks again. :)